# Is there a easy way to create a module in JBoss 7?

Tags: java, jboss

Is there some interface that we can create a module, like I can create a datasource, or every module I have to create manually?

What is the simplest way to create a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such interface as far as I know. Simplest way is to just create the folder structure and module.xml and copy the jars there.

If you're creating them out of dependencies from a Maven repo, you can use Maven and dependency-plugin to ease the creation of module.xml, but it will mostly ease out on getting the .jars. It doesn't really make the process any simpler.